# Does the verb 'to provide' collocate with the word 'feature'?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, collocation

In a computer science report, is it correct to say the following sentence:

> A certain package provides multiple features.

In other words, does the verb to *provide* collocate with the word *feature*?

Comment: Yes, you can say "provides" or "offers" or simply "has".  But if you're going to use **provides**, one would typically expect a modifying clause identifying the purpose, e.g. ...provides multiple features *for image manipulation*.

Comment: I don't think the collocation existed before modern electronics, (and particularly software); but it certainly does now.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the sentence.  Whether the two words "collocate" or not is irrelevant.

Comment: To say that two words *collocate* is different from saying that two words are okay together. Your words are fine, but they probably aren't a collocation.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, *features* are said to be ***offered***

> *A certain package offers multiple features*

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the sentence. Whether the two words "collocate" or not is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

Did you look up the meanings of to provide? The origin is Latin pro- before, forward and videre to see. So the basic meaning is to see something in advance.

If Caesar saw in advance that the cereal for his legion would not suffice, the consequence was that he took care to get cereal and to have cereal delivered.

So to provide has an astonishing semantic development from to see to the verb to deliver or to make something available for someone. To provide + features is possible.

Comment: The last paragraph is right. The first two paragraphs are completely irrelevant to the question, and commit the etymoogical fallacy.